# What does "conducive to the public good" mean in UK immigration laws?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration

What does "conducive to the public good" mean in UK immigration laws?

Comment: If you want to know what a law means, you may want to visit our sister site [law.se] instead. We can only help with travel related questions, and it's not clear how your question is related to travel within the scope defined in the [help center](/help/on-topic).

Comment: Whatever the secretary of state wants it to mean.

Answer (score 9):

It is a general catch-all for keeping people out who might engage in criminal, anti-social or politically divisive activity.

It literally means: "Is the presence of this individual in the UK going to be good for the UK public?"

Answer (score 5):

It relates to the character, conduct, and associations of an individual wanting to enter the UK https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/827971/GGFR-Section-1-v29.0-EXT.PDF

For example:

• a person is a member of a proscribed group

• a person is suspected of war crimes or crimes against humanity

• a person’s presence is undesirable because of their character, conduct or associations

• a person’s presence might lead to an infringement of UK law or a breach of public order

• a person’s presence may lead to an offence being committed by someone else